# Connect to PostgreSQL database with QtSQL using Connection Service File

Tags: postgresql, qt, pyqt, qtsql

I am using PyQt5 and PostgreSQL 13. My system has a [Connection Service File](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgservice.html) where service "`foo`" is defined.

How can I connect to that service using [Qt SQL](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-index.html)?

I found nothing on https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qpsql

For psycopg2 it would look like `conn = psycopg2.connect(service='foo')`

An answer for C++ Qt would be fine, it is easy to adapt code to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [QSqlDatabase::setConnectOptions()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqldatabase.html#setConnectOptions) you can specify `service` as a connection option.

Comment: That looks nice! I haven't been able to find an authoritative proof that it will work but it looks highly likely. Thank you!

Comment: If not please create a bug report so it can be fixed. But since those options are only passed through the psql driver I don't see a reason it should not work.